# Get key of an object when the key is an object

Tags: javascript, object

```js
let obj1 = {
    1: 1
};

let obj2 = {};
obj2[obj1] = 2;

let keys = Object.keys(obj2);

// first
for (let key of keys) {
  console.log(key) // [object Object]
}

for (let prop in obj2) {
  console.log(prop) // [object Object]
}

let key = keys[0];

// second
console.log(typeof key); // string
console.log(JSON.stringify(key) === JSON.stringify(obj1)); // false

// thirth
console.log(obj2['[object Object]']); // 2

obj2[{}] = 3;

// fourth
console.log(obj2['[object Object]']); // 3
console.log(obj2[obj1]); // 3
```

I have 4 questions:

**1/.** In the first: is there a way to get object

```
{
    1: 1
}
```

instead of `[object object]`?

**2/.** In the second: why am I getting `string` when trying to get the type of an object (not `object`)?

**3/.** In the thirth: the key of an object is an object. So, why can I assign it via a string?

**4/.** In the fourth: after adding another object to `obj2`, `obj1` has been overridden although `{}` is different from `obj1` (not duplicate key). Why?

Comment: Before assigning the `key`, make it `JSON.stringify`... I am really curious about how you came across such use-case...

Comment: "when the key is an object"?? Keys are _always strings_, though a string may look like an object.

Comment: When you do this: `obj2[obj1]  = 2` it converts `obj1` into a new string value in exactly the same way that `console.log()` does to produce `"[object Object]"`.  So what you're doing is equivalent to `obj2["[object Object]"] = 2`.  When you literally do the same thing later you're just replacing the value - not adding a new one

Comment: [_Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the `toString` method._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Property_names)

Comment: @Teemu Can you edit my question title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript objects can only use strings for keys. Thus, `obj2[obj1] = 2` is equivalent to `obj2[obj1.toString()] = 2`; and `obj1.toString()` is `"[object Object]"`. Thus, your `obj2` is, in fact, `{ "[object Object]": 2 }`.

1. You can't get what isn't there.
2. Because it isn't an object.
3. No, it isn't.
4. `{}.toString()` is same as `({ 1: 1 }).toString()`, so... you can see where this leads.

Comment: [_MDN Reference_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Property_names)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an object.

> The Map object is a simple key/value map. Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.